# Selenium with PhantomJS, click() not working

Tags: google-chrome, python

I have a working script to manipulate a site. When running with `webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver.exe)` it works like a charm. But when I try with `webdriver.PhantomJS(phantomjs.exe)` it doesn't work.

More specifically, what doesn't work is the click() in a `a` tag, the HTML is the following:

`<a href="javascript:;" class="foo" original-title=""><div class="icon_bar"></div></a>`

I get this element via `self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name('foo')` and then set it to a var, there are tons of it. Then I create a loop and call `current.click()`.

The thing is that it isn't really clicking, if I check the site manually nothing has changed.

- Python 3.4.2
- Selenium 2.44.0
- Windows 8.1

Comment: I have same problem with Java :-/

Comment: I also have found that click() doesn't work with Selenium and Phantom.js webdriver. This link will help you: https://hjrlive.wordpress.com/2014/04/29/clicking-on-an-element-in-phantom-js-using-javascript-and-webdriver/

Answer (score 1):

It's known that PhantomJS doesn't always work as expected on some websites. You could use tricks/hacks like `send_key(Keys.RETURN)` on that tag. You could also try clicking an image, or other tag. Also you can get the href, and then calling it with `driver.get(yourhiref)`.

Other thing is that, Do you only need one of those elements? Or to click on every element at `find_elements_by_class_name('foo')`? Because if it's the first case i would use xpath and css selector like this:

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@Class='foo']/div")[n].click()`

or

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@Class='foo']")[n].click()`

where n is the child you are looking for.

PS: I would go for a Headless Firefox instead of PhantomJS